# How to change css styles of a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this test page: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=305

I am trying to make the form towards the middle of the page look nicer.  When I look at it in FireBug, there is a lot of padding space on the sides of that tabs from this div:

```
<div id="tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
```

How can I change the space padding on the sides of the divs to be less pixels?  Also, is there a way to make the black strip across the tabs all black?

Thanks!

Comment: Which from do you mean? I see two in that div, one bigger, one smaller. And what do you mean by the "black strip"?

Comment: In Firebug (IIRC), all of the matched CSS rules also have a source. On Chrome, at least, Inspector gives me the line number of the CSS styles that are affecting that element.

Comment: @ACarter that bigger form that is lower. :)

Comment: @Blender I think the line number is in their library which I am calling remotely.

Comment: Right. Look at the CSS rule. Just copy that block of text into your stylesheet and modify it.

Comment: @GeekedOut Okay. Do you still need a hand with this, or have the given answers done it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the css defined by jQuery UI css in your application css file or on the page.
You can set the padding as below and override all the required styles in the same way.

```
.ui-tabs-panel{
   padding: 0px !important;//define the style as per your need
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The lazy way would be to set important property in your css.

```
#tabs-1{padding-left: some lesser value !important}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the padding is getting added because each form element is wrapped inside a paragraph `<p>` tag.  The style is applied to just the p element in your stylesheet, so you can overwrite it with the following: `#add_suggested_solution p {margin:0 0 0 0}` .  Note, replace the 0's with whatever your desired margin is.

What is the black stripe that you are referring to?

Comment: the black stripe is the one that has the 3 tabs